# Getting Error while cleaning all files and folders from desktop and moving it to a BACKUP folder in desktop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
set a="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%"
For /F "tokens=1-5 delims=/-" %%A in ('Date /t') do (SET CurrentDate=%%A%%B%%C)
::echo hi
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%"
::echo dir made
dir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ /S /B > %TEMP%\files.txt
::echo done
For /F %%A in (%TEMP%\files.txt) do move %%A "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%\"
del %TEMP%\files.txt
```

Having a torrid time with the above script:
- it creates the folder nicely with proper date
-creates the file in temp and redirects the output from the list in the desktop
- But after that it gives error. The path specified could not be found
i tried many things but its not working. Could you please let me know how can i move files and folders in the desktop to a folder BACKUP in the desktop. so that my desktop looks clean. And i would also like to exclude some items from being moved.

Comment: Getting error The system cannot find the file specified.please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `for` statement to this:

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%TEMP%\files.txt") do move "%%A" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%\"
```

Also, the way it is currently, your destination directory will have a space at the end, and it'll try to move Desktop BU into itself.  Finally, there's no need for the /s switch in your `dir` command, as moving a directory will move all its children anyway.  Try this instead:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set CurrentDate=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%
set desktop=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
dir "%desktop%" /B | find /v "Desktop BU"> "%TEMP%\files.txt"
mkdir "%desktop%\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%" 2>NUL
For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%TEMP%\files.txt") do move "%desktop%\%%A" "%desktop%\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%\"
del "%TEMP%\files.txt"
```

Or here's another way that doesn't require an intermediate `files.txt`:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set CurrentDate=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%
set desktop=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
mkdir "%desktop%\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%" 2>NUL
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "%desktop%" /b ^| find /v "Desktop BU"') do (
    move "%desktop%\%%A" "%desktop%\Desktop BU\%CurrentDate%\"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working perfect. I found the mistakes i made, but i have 1 doubt, when i use dir /s /b , its not working with the full path. I don't understand why.. so i have to give %desktop%\%%a..

Comment: %date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4% --This solved the date purpose. I figured out that the code i was using for date was creating the issue. And thats why i was getting error,The specified path could not be found. With this date formatting, it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The script is working fine in windows 7 but its not working in Windows XP. Please help in case of XP

Comment: now its working fine with double quotes but i had to remove the set desktop="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop", instead give the variable at their required positions. move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%A". It working fine for me. Thanks

Comment: dir "%desktop%" /B | find /v "Desktop BU"> "%TEMP%\files.txt" Need to exclude multiple directories from the find command. whats the best way to exclude multiple folders in windows batch files

Comment: The above answer was really helpful for me and i have accepted it by clicking on the right icon and it turned green.. Am i missing some thing? please let me know.

Comment: @user1765220 - The `find /v` is what exluces the "Desktop BU" directory.  There's a similar command, `findstr`, that'll let you exclude multiple items.  `findstr /v /c:"Desktop BU" /c:"Excluded folder 2" /c:"Excluded folder 3" etc.`  Regarding the check mark, you aren't missing a thing.  I left that comment before you clicked the check mark.  Thank you :)